# Bean validation doesn't work with mojarra 2.2.4

Tags: jsf, bean-validation, mojarra, jsf-2.2

I'm trying to use Hibernate Validator 5.0.1 and JSF2.2 but their integration seems to be broken since mojarra version 2.2.3. I've created small app to demonstrate the issue and get exception  "javax.servlet.ServletException: Expression Error: Named Object: javax.faces.Bean not found." when running it on Tomcat 7.0.42.

Does anyone else have this problem?

webapp/pages/index.xhtml:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
  <h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:messages/>
        <h:inputText value="#{theBean.z}">
            <f:validateBean/>
        </h:inputText>
        <h:commandButton value="send z"/>
    </h:form>
  </h:body>
  </html>
```

TheBean.java

```
package lo.test;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;

@ManagedBean
public class TheBean {

    @Min(5)
    private Integer z;

    public Integer getZ() {
        return z;
    }

    public void setZ(Integer z) {
        this.z = z;
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>pages/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Dependencies:

```
"org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.0.1.Final"
"com.sun.faces:jsf-impl:2.2.4"
"com.sun.faces:jsf-api:2.2.4"
```

Full stack trace of exception:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: Expression Error: Named Object: javax.faces.Bean not found.
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createValidator(ApplicationImpl.java:1596)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ValidatorTagHandlerDelegateImpl.createValidator(ValidatorTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:245)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ValidatorTagHandlerDelegateImpl.applyAttachedObject(ValidatorTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:133)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ValidatorTagHandlerDelegateImpl.applyNested(ValidatorTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:212)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ValidatorTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ValidatorTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:88)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:190)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:190)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:190)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:161)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:980)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Can you also add your full stack trace?

Comment: I've got the same problem with hibernate validator 5.0.1 and Mojarra >= 2.2.3. 2.2.2 works fine for me as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix it this way:

```
public static final String BEANS_VALIDATION_AVAILABILITY_CACHE_KEY = "javax.faces.BEANS_VALIDATION_AVAILABLE";

@PostConstruct
private void init() {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getApplicationMap().remove(BEANS_VALIDATION_AVAILABILITY_CACHE_KEY);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getApplicationMap()
            .put(BeanValidator.VALIDATOR_FACTORY_KEY, Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to occur with Mojarra 2.2.3 to 2.2.6 on servlet containers like Tomcat or Jetty as Mojarra tries to load bean validation via JNDI.

I discussed this with Ed Burns at JavaLand 2014 and this issue should be fixed with Mojarra 2.2.7 (see [JAVASERVERFACES-3183](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3183)).

Answer (score 2):

This is does work with Mojara 2.2.2 but doesn't with newer versions. Thanks to Michail for the hint. Here is another way to preconfigure Faces:

```
public class FacesContextBootstrap implements ServletContextListener
{
    public static final String BEANS_VALIDATION_AVAILABILITY_CACHE_KEY = "javax.faces.BEANS_VALIDATION_AVAILABLE";

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getApplicationMap().remove(BEANS_VALIDATION_AVAILABILITY_CACHE_KEY);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getApplicationMap()
                .put(BeanValidator.VALIDATOR_FACTORY_KEY, Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory());
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {

    }
}
```

Comment: this fix doesn't appear to work for me on Majorra 2.2.6 - did you place the FacesContextBootstrap class in a specific place in the project hierarchy?

Comment: The faces context appear not to be initialized at the moment that the servlet container is initialized

Answer (score 2):

Check the following:

```
ApplicationFactory applicationFactory = (ApplicationFactory) FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.APPLICATION_FACTORY);

applicationFactory.getApplication().addDefaultValidatorId(BeanValidator.VALIDATOR_ID);
applicationFactory.getApplication().addValidator(BeanValidator.VALIDATOR_ID, BeanValidator.class.getName());
```

Comment: Worked for me using Tomcat Tomcat 6.0.39, JSF 2.2.6 and Hibernate Bean Validator 4.3.1

Comment: Yes, me too! This bug was driving me crazy and I was quite sure that it had to be one of the many bugs in JSF (sigh!) P.S. Using Tomcat 7.0.53, JSF 2.2.6 and Hibernate Bean Validator 5.1.1 –  Kounavi