# PrimeFaces client side validation does not work with inplace editor

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces

I have the following faces code:

```
<h:outputText value="Name: "/>
<!--<p:inplace id="inplace" editor="true" emptyLabel="N/A">-->
<p:inputText id="name" value="#{testBean.name}" label="Name"/>
<!--</p:inplace>-->

<p:commandButton value="Save" validateClient="true" ajax="false" update="form"/>
```

And TestBean is:

```
public class TestBean
{
    @Size(min=2,max=5)
    private String name;
}
```

In the way it presented above validation **works**, but as soon as I uncomment the lines to introduce inplace editor for this field validation does not happen.

Isn't *inplace* element just designed for validation or I'm doing anything wrong ? I feel it is due to the fact that *inputText* is actually invisible.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be related to not properly configured JSF implementation, in this case it is Mojarra 2.2.5. See this topic: [Bean validation doesn't work with mojarra 2.2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19637996/bean-validation-doesnt-work-with-mojarra-2-2-4/)